# How to send data from post request to get request

Tags: express

I have the data in a function and want to send it to get request as it has accepts input and those inputs are just present in post request.

```
const getUsers = async (type,subtype) =>{
    const items = await getDocs(type);
    const tempList = []
      items.docs.map((d)=>{
        if(d.data().subtype===subtype){
          tempList.push(d.data())

        }
      });
      return tempList[getRndInteger(0,tempList.length)];
};

const searchBar = async (type,subtype)=>{
  let val = "";
  switch(type){
    case "documentry":
       val = await getUsers(documentryLinks,subtype);
      return val;
      break;
    case "song":
       val = getUsers(songLinks,subtype);
      return val;
      break;
    case "food":
       val = getUsers(foodLinks,subtype);
      return val;
      break;
  }

}

app.route("/").get(async (req,res)=>{
  res.send(getVal);
}).post(async (req,res)=>{
  const type = req.body.type;
  const subtype = req.body.subtype;
  getVal = await searchBar(type,subtype);
  res.send(getVal);
})
```

Since these inputs are passed just from post request, how do I call this in get request. Kindly help.

Comment: Does your solution not work?

Comment: it works. but i feel I am doing it all wrong. and I dont know how to gather data in post requeset and forward that to get request. can you please help in that